# Click handlers on links not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension in which I have

popup.html where I call jquery.js, popup.js and link.js

```
    ...
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
    <script src="link.js"></script>
  </head>
```

popup.js

```
var streamGenerator = {

  /* Twitch URL to the top 20 streams */
  searchOnTwitch_: 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?limit=20',

  /* XHR Request to grab those streams */
  requestStreams: function() {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", this.searchOnTwitch_, true);
    req.onload = this.showStreams_;
    req.send(null);
  },

  /* onload event inserting the streams into the DOM */
  showStreams_: function(e) {
    var streams = JSON.parse(e.target.responseText).streams;

    for (var i=0; i < streams.length; i++) {
      var stream = {
        game: streams[i].game,
        name: streams[i].channel.name,
        viewers: streams[i].viewers,
        link: streams[i].channel.url,
      };

      $('tbody').append('<tr>'
        + '<td>' + stream.game + '</td>'
        + '<td>' + '<a href=' + stream.link + '>' + stream.name + '</a></td>'
        + '<td>' + stream.viewers + '</td></a>'
      );
    }
  }
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  streamGenerator.requestStreams();
});
```

and then link.js

```
$(function() {
  $('a').click(function(){
    chrome.tabs.create({url: $(this).attr('href')});
  });
})
```

The popup works and show what it is supposed to show, but the links don't open a new tab.

If I go to chrome's console, I don't get any error, but if I copy/paste the link.js jquery, the links work after;

What am I doing wrong?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code loads `popup.js` *before* `link.js`. The relevant parts are executed in the following order:

```
// popup.js
$(function() {
    $('a').click( ... );
})
// link.js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    streamGenerator.requestStreams(); //<-- Creates the links
});
```

`$(func)` is roughly equal to `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', func)`, so what you're doing is actually something like:

```
// Run after the DOMContentLoaded "domready" event:
$('a').click(...);
streamGenerator.requestStreams(); // Creates the links
```

First, you're binding the `click` event to all existing anchors (none). Hereafter you're adding the new links. This sequence is obviously not going to work.

It can be solved by swapping the order of `popup.js` and `link.js`, or by using [event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/event-delegation/info):

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function() {
    chrome.tabs.create({url: this.href});
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works! Can you explain more why popup.js is being loaded before link.js, even if it's before in the dom?

Comment: Well, `<script src="popup.js">` comes before `<script src="link.js">`.

Comment: Sorry I meant the opposite... you switched both scripts in your answer... but popup.js is supposed to be loaded before link.js.
link.js is the script with the .click event handler to create the tabs.

Comment: Ah, well, it's still a timing issue: `popup.js` runs an AJAX request, which takes some time to complete. When the request completes, the handler which inserts the `<a>` elements runs *after* `$('a').click(...)` has run.